# Python shows Memory Error

Tags: python-2.7

I tried a very simple python script, which be used to add certain strings in each row, the code is:

```
import csv
List = []
list = []
csv_reader = csv.reader(open('moz_press_IDE_mdoc.csv'))
i = 0
for row in csv_reader:
    List.append(list)
    j = 1
    for num in row:
        tmp = str(i) + ':'
        num = tmp + num
        j += 1
        List[i].append(num)
    i += 1

out = open('newCSV.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(out)
csv_writer.writerow(List)
out.close()
```

It shows the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "preprocess.py", line 19, in <module>
    csv_writer.writerow(List)
MemoryError
```

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
List.append(list)
```

doesn't do what you think it does. It appends a fresh reference to the existing variable.

Instead, write

```
List.append([])
```

because (I think) you want a new empty list, not a new reference to the one you manipulated in the previous loop iteration. Print out `List` before passing it to `csv.writer()` to see the difference.

And *please* don't use `list` as a variable name, because it masks the builtin type. That makes your code hard to read and may lead to mystifying bugs.